# How to combine the data with name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
DataFrame A:

 Date        Code  Marks
 2020-01-01    X     5
 2020-01-02    Y     7
       ...


 DataFrame B:
 Date       Code Win Lose
 2020-01-01  X    8    1
 2020-01-02  Y    0    6

 The performance i needed:
 Date         Code  Marks Win Lose
 2020-01-01     X    5     8  1
 2020-01-02     Y    7     0  6
```

I want to combine dataframes with there name(code)
how can I do this
thx!

Comment: Read about [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

Comment: `pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Date', 'Code'])`

Answer (score 0):

```
A = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Date": ["2020-01-01", "2020-01-02",],
        "Code": ["X", "Y"],
        "Marks": ["5", "7"]
    },
)
B = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Date": ["2020-01-01", "2020-01-02",],
        "Code": ["X", "Y"],
        "Win": ["8", "0"],
        "Lose": ["1", "6"]

    },
)

result = pd.merge(A, B, on=["Code", "Date"])
```

Here's the answer to your question, I would advice looking up the doc if you need something : https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html because it's very helpful...